# Why doesn't XeF6 displace oxygen from water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, oxidation-state, reactivity, hydrolysis

Consider the following reactions (unbalanced):

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{XeF2 + H2O &→ Xe + HF + O2} \tag{a} \\
\ce{XeF4 + H2O &→ XeO3 + Xe + O2 + HF} \tag{b} \\
\ce{XeF6 + H2O &→ XeO3 + HF} \tag{c}
\end{align}
$$

Considering that the oxidizing power order of the xenon fluorides is $\ce{XeF6} > \ce{XeF4} > \ce{XeF2},$ I don't understand why $\ce{XeF6}$ is unable to oxidize $\ce{O^2-}$ (in water) to $\ce{O2}.$ $\ce{XeF2}$ and $\ce{XeF4}$ are able to achieve this (rather difficult) oxidation, but $\ce{XeF6}$ is unable despite having greater oxidizing power.

*Note*: I have a primitive understanding on this topic and a deep and elaborate explanation will be appreciated. Also, an explanation of the reasoning behind each individual reaction ( for example, why only $\ce{XeF4}$ disproportionates?) will be even better.

Comment: XeO and XeO2 do not exist. Also you're oversimplifying what happens when XeF6 reacts with water - at least 3 equations would be needed.

Comment: XeO2 is known (https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja110618g) and its synthesis is via hydrolysis of XeF4

Comment: My guess: Xenon difluoride and xenon tetrafluoride produces xenon(II) oxide as intermediates which is unstable and disproportionates to xenon, xenon(VI) oxide and oxide and that's what you see in the products. Xenon hexafluoride also hydrolyses but as xenon oxide fluorides as intermediates which ultimately converts to xenon(VI) oxide. So, it is necessary for you to break down the reaction and balance them because the reaction are not that simple. See: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01065a009

Comment: Section 8.4 and 8.7 of [Arrow Pushing in Inorganic Chemistry: A Logical Approach to the Chemistry of the Main‐Group Elements](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118924525) give mechanisms for these reactions. These are not mechanisms which have actually been proven to be true just like most of the book, but nevertheless they convincingly explain why we get the products that we do in these reactions.

Comment: @AshishAhuja Could you please convert the content of sections 8.4 and 8.7 into an answer as I can’t access the link you mentioned.

Comment: @ShashwatTomar Search for the book on zlib, I had downloaded a pdf from there. I don't think I have much to add to what is given in the book, so any answer I write will basically just be a blatant copy paste, which I think will fall under plagiarism.